# Android is closing the application from the front while waiting but the process is still alive in the background

Tags: java, android

I have an app that uses Google Plus registration, my issue is:

After calling `mGoogleApiClient.connect();` and then I have nothing to do except wait for response from gPlus to either fail `onConnectionFailed` or `onConnected`.

But while waiting for it, a strange thing happens. My mobile screen gets a little dimmer like it happens when a dialog has to come up but nothing comes up and application is closed after 1,2 seconds.

However the process is still running because when either `onConnectionFailed` or `onConnected` are hit (breakpoints) I can catch them in debugger and move along the statement but there the application (view) is closed over mobile.

Why might this be happening, and how can I resolve this issue?

```
private void activateGooglePlusLogin() {
        SignInButton googlePlusSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.googlePlusSignInButton);
        googlePlusSignInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
        googlePlusSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try {
                    eGooglePlus googleApiObj = new eGooglePlus(Splash.this);
                    googleApiObj.connectGoogleApi();

                    TextView pleaseWait = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pleaseWait);
                    pleaseWait.setText("Please wait while we register your account...");
                    //waitForNSeconds(10000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void connectGoogleApi() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mainAppContext).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```